# Select comments on all objects of a table and object informations

Tags: postgresql

I have this query that can select all comments on objects of tables (+ the commet on the table itself):

```
SELECT c.table_schema, c.table_name,pgd.description, pgd.objsubid
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_all_tables as st
  inner join pg_catalog.pg_description pgd on (pgd.objoid=st.relid)
  inner join information_schema.tables c on (c.table_schema=st.schemaname and c.table_name=st.relname);
```

But this only shows the subid of the objects. Now I want to be able to know what object exactly this is (column, primary key, foreign key, ...) and what the name is.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you join with `information_schema.tables`, you will get only information about tables, views and foreign tables. These can be disambiguated by adding the `table_type` column from `information_schema.tables`.

To get comments about all kinds of objects, you'd have to `UNION ALL` queries for each object type.

For example, to get comments on functions and procedures, you'll have to join with `pg_proc`:

```
SELECT f.proname, d.description
FROM pg_description AS d
   JOIN pg_proc AS f ON f.oid = d.objoid
WHERE d.classoid = 'pg_proc'::regclass;
```

Comment: Thanks. That's bad news I guess. Is there maybe a way to for now only get the name of the object?

Comment: Hmm, no, sorry. You have to get the object to get its name. But it is not that hard. I have added how to do it for functions as an example.